# Python pandas format datetime.datetime objects that are added to list

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The df this is going through has the countries as column names and the dates in the first row.

[image]

What Im trying to do is check for each country in the list the respective column and in every row where it says 'Worked' return the date from that row in the date column. What I get as a return for a single date is this :

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 0, 0)]
```

The format I need it in is 201901 to use this then further to create filenames. Thats why I added the str() because otherwise I cannot create combination of dates and countries to filenames. My only solution so far would be to strip and format this string further, but I dont think that is the best solution.

```
dates[]   

for country in lst :

    dates.append(str(df.lookup((df.loc[df[country] == 'Worked'].index),['Date'])))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [
    datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,0),datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,0,0,0),datetime.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0,0),
        ],
    "Country":["Worked","Uploaded","Worked"],
})
dates = df[df["Country"]=="Worked"]["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y%m").tolist()
dates = [x + '_country.xlsx' for x in dates]

# dates should now look like this:
# ['201701_country.xlsx', '201901_country.xlsx']
```

Here I used `.dt` to access datetime specific functions, and `strftime()` converts it to the desired date and time format.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is the full list of `%Y` type characters, and what they mean

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, what I get as a result of this now looks like this:
36    201901
Name: Date Scope, dtype: object

I am struggeling on how to use this now to create for example a string filename looking like this : 201901_country.xlsx. I guess I somehow have to convert it back into a string?

Comment: Hello, I just did an edit, does that help? Is there only one "Worked" row?

Answer (score 1):

```
This should work, check it out.

dates = []   

for country in lst :

    dates.append(df[df.Country == country].Date.dt.strftime("%Y%m"))
```